# Character encoding changes after exploding

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii, explode

I'm trying this script but the character encoding keeps changing:

```
    $v1 = "text1";
    $v2 = "text2";
    $v3 = "text3";

    $result = encrypt($v1 . ":" . $v2 . ":" . $v3, SALT);
    $result = decrypt($result , SALT);
    list($v1, $v2, $v3) = explode(":", $result);
    echo mb_detect_encoding($v1); // gives ASCII
    echo mb_detect_encoding($v2); // gives ASCII
    echo mb_detect_encoding($v3); // gives UTF-8 <<<<
```

BUT by adding another var it gives:

```
    $v1 = "text1";
    $v2 = "text2";
    $v3 = "text3";
    $result = encrypt($v1 . ":" . $v2 . ":" . $v3. ":COTROLFLAG", SALT);
    $result = decrypt($result , SALT);
    list($v1, $v2, $v3, $v4) = explode(":", $result);
    echo mb_detect_encoding($v1); // gives ASCII
    echo mb_detect_encoding($v2); // gives ASCII
    echo mb_detect_encoding($v3); // gives ASCII <<<<
    echo mb_detect_encoding($v4); // gives ASCII
```

Can any one help me?

These are the encrypt and decrypt functions:

```
    function encrypt($str, $key)
    {
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('des', 'ecb');
        if (($pad = $block - (strlen($str) % $block)) < $block) {
            $str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
        }
        $result = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
        return $result;
    }
    function decrypt($str, $key)
    {
        $str = base64_decode($str);
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $str = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('des', 'ecb');
        $pad = ord($str[($len = strlen($str)) - 1]);
        if ($pad && $pad < $block && preg_match('/' . chr($pad) . '{' . $pad . '}$/i', $str)) {
            return substr($str, 0, strlen($str) - $pad);
        }
        return $str;
    }
```

---

after the first answer i knew where i should search for a solution..

I found this to pad and strip:

```
function addpadding($string, $blocksize = 32){
    $len = strlen($string);
    $pad = $blocksize - ($len % $blocksize);
    $string .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    return $string;
}
function strippadding($string){
    $slast = ord(substr($string, -1));
    $slastc = chr($slast);
    $pcheck = substr($string, -$slast);
    if(preg_match("/$slastc{".$slast."}/", $string)){
        $string = substr($string, 0, strlen($string)-$slast);
        return $string;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The changed encryption and decryption functions:

```
function encrypt($str, $key)
{   
    global $domain;
    $key = base64_decode($key);
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    setcookie("IV_CODE", $iv, time()+86400, "/", $domain);//more security

    $enc = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, addpadding($str), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
    return $enc;
}
function decrypt($str, $key)
{
    $str = base64_decode($str);
    $iv = (isset($_COOKIE['IV_CODE'])) ? base64_decode($_COOKIE['IV_CODE']) : 0;
    if ($iv != 0) {
        $key = base64_decode($key);
        $dec = strippadding(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));    
        return $dec;
    }
    return false;
}
```

thank you

Comment: What is `$admin`? What do you think `mb_detect_encoding` does, it's completely useless and you don't seem to know that.

Comment: sorry .. it should be `$result`... i only forgot to change it in this mini script...

i got a bug in my script because some to vars are not having the same charset encoding... the first one i do pull it from MySQL DB.. the other one from the cookies and i do compare both after decrypting the cookie value.. since it becomes utf-8 there will be always a difference...
so i added `mb_detect_encoding` to check the values... so you understand what i mean

Comment: Note that *Cookies* are not secure. They can be read by the user, changed by the user, and are transferred unencrypted over the www for every request, if you do not use HTTPs. So they can also be sniffed from network traffic.

Comment: they are encrypted !! this is the idea of the whole thing !!! instead of `setcookie("user", "johnysmith", time()+3600*24, "/");` we can use encrypted values... 
`setcookie("user", encrypt("johnysmith", KEY), time()+3600*24, "/");` 
and it would be transferred like this `NXip4/4quhv5QGME/IOI9aD+d/mpUMMPr+jsx3ZY+JU=`

Comment: But the IV code is not encrypted, you wrote "more security" next to where you set it, hence my comment ;)

Comment: is it not useless without the key ?!

Comment: Now I got mixed up myself. So while the IV does apparently provide some increased security even if it is sent along with the encrypted string (I'm no expert however), writing "increased security" next to where you set a cookie is just so wrong ;) However, since the more an attacker knows about an encryption the more likely he can break it, you should at least think about whether it is possible to transfer your IV through alternate means.

Comment: i can set some id code in the cookies and put the IV codes list in a MySQL Table.... would that be an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with explode, it's your encrypt and decrypt functions. I will hazard a guess and say that this

```
if (($pad = $block - (strlen($str) % $block)) < $block) {
    $str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}
```

has something to do with what was mentioned about `AES_256` in [**this post on php.net**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php#105985). (You should probably keep in mind what it says about `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` too)

However, there is a lot wrong with your code in the `decrypt()` function. For example your Regex pattern is easily broken if the padding length is `27`. It also should absolutely not be case-insensitive. However, it is probably easier and certainly faster to just extract the substring and compare it using `==` like

```
$substr = substr($str, -$pad);
if ($pad && $pad < $block && $substr == str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad)) {
    return substr($str, 0, -$pad);
}
```

Comment: if found these pad and strip functions:
function addpadding($string, $blocksize = 32){
    $len = strlen($string);
    $pad = $blocksize - ($len % $blocksize);
    $string .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    return $string;
}
function strippadding($string){
    $slast = ord(substr($string, -1));
    $slastc = chr($slast);
    $pcheck = substr($string, -$slast);
    if(preg_match("/$slastc{".$slast."}/", $string)){
        $string = substr($string, 0, strlen($string)-$slast);
        return $string;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

Comment: Well that you found them (presumably on the web somewhere) does not mean they are correct.

Comment: sure not! but seems to be ok to me... and my problem is solved...
what do you think?

Comment: I think that a padding of 27 will still be a problem (or any other PCRE magic characters)

Comment: @user1968819 it will also fail if your string contains any substring that matches against `/\xNN{NN}/` where NN is the charcode of the last character in the string, as the pattern is missing a final `$` to align it to the string end. Additionally all of these will produce corrupted output if you encode a string that ends with N characters of keycode N and requires no padding. To circumvent this case you should probably add an additional character when **encoding** if the string length is `mod $blocksize`

Comment: thnx i'll keep that in mind until i figure out how to manage it right

Comment: I gave you a hint for all cases in my comment already ;) though I still think you should drop the PCRE function and use string comparison instead like I wrote in the answer. Ultimately it's up to you though.